# Multidimensional Arrays and one of the fields

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

There is a multi-d array and I want to reach specific field in it. I have look around it but I was unable to find proper answer to my question.

My array is like that;

```
array-md
columns--  0 | 1  | 2

index 0 - [1][John][Doe]
index 1 - [2][Sue][Allen]
index 2 - [3][Luiz][Guzman]
.
.
.
index n - [n+1][George][Smith]
```

My question is how can I reach only second column of the array? I tried `name = array[loop][1];` but it says "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference". What is the right way to do that?

Here is main part of the code.

---

get

---

```
var lpx:int;
var lpxi:int;
var arrLen:int = Info.endPageArray.length;

for(lpx = 0; lpx < arrLen; lpx++)
{
    for(lpxi = Info.endPageArray[lpx][2]; lpxi < Info.endPageArray[lpx][1]; lpxi++)
    {
        if(Info._intervalSearch[lpxi] == "completed")
        {
            successCount++;
            Info._unitIntervalSuccess.push([lpx, successCount / (Info._intervalSearch.length / 100)]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

set

---

```
for(lpix = 0; lpix < arrayLength; lpix++)
{
    if(lpix + 1 <= arrayLength)
    {
        Info.endPageArray.push([lpix, Info._UnitsTriggers[lpix + 1], Info._UnitsTriggers[lpix]]);
    }
    else
    {
        Info.endPageArray.push([lpix, Info._UnitsTriggers[lpix], Info._UnitsTriggers[lpix - 1]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be the right way to do it. Show us the code, because otherwise we have to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure that your question and the code that you've added are related ?! Please add just the part where you've added your data to the array and that where you get it from the array...

Comment: @akmozo I updated the question and added the part where I `push` the array. But if it is the way of doing it, there won't be a problem, probably something else.

Comment: You know that your `else` in the `for` loop of the `set` part will never be executed because `lpix` is always `< arrayLength` ?!

Comment: I highly recommend using objects for each entry.

Comment: @null one object per row? or does object have array.length numbers of member/item? It is like Flashist's answer, right?

Comment: @coner One object per person. You have a list of people and your code becomes a lot more readable if you model it as such, because you get named properties instead of indices to access it. Compare `people[3].surname` to `people[3][2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multidimensional array is an array of arrays, which you can create like this :

```
var persons:Array = [
    ['John', 'Doe'],
    ['Sue', 'Allen'],
    ['Luiz','Guzman']
];

var list:Array = [];

for(var i:int = 0; i < persons.length; i++)
{
     list.push([i + 1, persons[i][0], persons[i][1]]);
}

trace(list);
// gives : 
//
//  1, John, Doe
//  2, Sue, Allen
//  3, Luiz, Guzman
```

Then to get some data :

```
for(var j:int = 0; j < list.length; j++)
{
     trace(list[j][1]);     // gives for the 2nd line : Sue
}
```

For more about [multidimensional arrays](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee9.html) take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee9.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: `For the last part;
j=0 -> trace: Doe
j=1 -> trace: Allen
j=2 -> trace: Guzman`

so `trace(list[1][1]);//gives Sue` right?

Comment: @coner You can test it ;) but it gives : John, Sue, Luiz and Sue ... to get Doe, Allen and Guzman you should use `trace(list[j][2]);` ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var tempArr:Array = [];

function pushItem(itemName:String, itemSurname:String):void
{
    var tempIndex:int = tempArr.length;
    tempArr[tempIndex] = {};
    tempArr[tempIndex][tempIndex + 1] = {};
    tempArr[tempIndex][tempIndex + 1][name] = {};
    tempArr[tempIndex][tempIndex + 1][name][itemSurname] = {};
}

function getNameObject(index:int):Object
{
    var result:Object;

    if(index < tempArr.length)
    {
        result = tempArr[index][index + 1];
    }

    return result;
}

pushItem("Max", "Payne");
pushItem("Lara", "Croft");
pushItem("Dart", "Vader");

//
trace(getNameObject(0));
trace(getNameObject(1));
trace(getNameObject(2));
```